# How to model a Fastener with ABAQUS Connector in a Joint with four Plates

Tags: connector, abaqus

I have to model a joint with four plates connected by a Fastener.
So, I have modeled the four plates, with a hole in wchich the fastener is supposed to be.

Two Plates are constrained (in six DOF) and Two Plates are subjected to tensile distributed load as shown in the first picture.

[Figure 1: Layout, Restriction and Loading Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUntK.png)

The center of the hole of each Plate is a RP (reference point) used as the Control Point of Kinematic Coupling to the hole surface.

[Figure 2: RP and Kinematic Coupling for each hole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuuQd.png)

So I created three Connectors (MPC BEAM type) to connect the four plates. The three Connectors are "connected to each other", as shown in the Figure 3.

[Figure 3: Connectors (MPC BEAM type) connecting the four plates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyK8P.png)

The ABAQUS job results analysis are OK. Then, I created a set of connectors and then one History Output Request to obtain such forces resulting in the Connectors (see Figure 4).

[Figure 4: History Output Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p57tK.png)

Then, the job simply Aborted due to erros. The Error Message is the following:
" in keyword *ELEMENTOUTPUT, file "Triple_ShearJoint_04_CONNECTOR_Try02.inp", line 2514: Unknown assembly set FASTENERS

Element set assembly_fasteners has not been defined

Analysis Input File Processor exited with an error.".

So I need some help understand the correct way to get the Forces or indication of another way to model Connectors (a serie of three Connectors) to "work as Fastener connecting the four plates" and get the Forces on the Connectors.

I tried to use different types of ABAQUS Connector MPC Beam and Connector Basic (Cartesian).
The first one (Connector MPC Beam) exhibited good results while the second one did not work properly when 3 Connector were connected in serie..
The first one does not work when I do and Output Request, while with the second one I can get the loads.
So I expect to find a Connector and a "modus operandis" thar works OK and let me get the loads.